# Neuroph Studio requires JDK

Tags: java

When I launch Neuroph Studio, I get an error message that reads:

> **The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules**
> Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation or see https://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre for more information.

I have tried using the methods described in other posts and websites but none have fixed the error message, including downloading JDK, JRE, and have tried reinstalling Neuroph Studio. I also edited the config file and used the suggested `--jdkhome` command in the Command Prompt.

Comment: Have you downloaded JDK?  See https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

First ensure, you have installed JDK (The development kit, not the runtime JRE).

Then check if the correct Java is in your $PATH variable by typing `echo $PATH` (linux) or `path` (windows)
if this isn't the case do it as shown here:

https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/path-variable

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Neuroph Studio wants specifically jdk-1.8 . After installing it, the error message disappeared.